# Compile errors with Fortran90

Tags: compilation, fortran90, gfortran, photran

All, I've been fighting these errors for hours, here's my code:

```
program hello
implicit none
integer :: k, n, iterator
integer, dimension(18) :: objectArray

call SetVariablesFromFile()
do iterator = 1, 18
    write(*,*) objectArray(iterator)
end do


contains
subroutine SetVariablesFromFile()
    IMPLICIT NONE
    integer :: status, ierror, i, x

    open(UNIT = 1, FILE = 'input.txt', &
    ACTION = 'READ',STATUS = 'old', IOSTAT = ierror)
    if(ierror /= 0) THEN
        write(*, *) "Failed to open input.txt!"
        stop
    end if

    do i = 1, 18
        objectArray(i) = read(1, *, IOSTAT = status) x
        if (status > 0) then
            write(*,*) "Error reading input file"
            exit
        else if (status < 0) then
            write(*,*) "EOF"
            exit
        end if
    end do
    close(1)

END subroutine SetVariablesFromFile

end program hello
```

I'm getting compile errors:

1. make: *** [hello.o] Error1
2. Syntax error in argument list at (1)

I read online that the latter error could be due to a long line of code exceeding 132 characters, which doesn't appear to be the problem.I have no where to begin on the first error... any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
objectArray(i) = read(1, *, IOSTAT = status) x
```

is not valid Fortran. You need to write it as,

```
read(1,*,iostat=status) objectArray(i)
```

Setting it in this correct form, I received no compiler errors with ifort 12.1, nor with gfortran 4.4.3

Comment: Excellent, compiles now! Thank you